# How dynamically change char pointer size?

Tags: c, pointers

i use realloc for dynamically increase size of a char pointer(*seqA). is there another way to do is better?

it's part of my code:

```
    while((holder=fgetc(fileA)) != EOF) {
    lenA++;
    temp=(char*)realloc(seqA,lenA*sizeof(char));
    if (temp!=NULL) {
        seqA=temp;
    seqA[lenA-1]=holder;
    }
    else {
        free (seqA);
        puts ("Error (re)allocating memory");
        exit (1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `seqA` is its allocated dynamically?

Comment: What you can do (to increase execution speed and to decrease memory fragmentation) is to **minimize** the number of times you do reallocation. For example doubling the buffer size each time and keeping track of where the logical buffer end is.

Comment: Out of interest there's never any point in doing `* sizeof(char)` - that is 1 by definition. Chars can have a different number of bits in them in different systems but sizeof is still 1.

Comment: first of all you should mention where seqA is initialized and is memory allocated to it dynamically(using malloc/calloc)....
One way to improve execution is by allocating maximum dynamic memory to seqA by estimating at max how much memory it will need...this way you may remove realloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code is reading in the complete file into a string, why not use the following code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

....

struct stat buf;
fstat(fileno(fileA), &buf);
seqA = malloc(buf.st_size);
fread(seqA, buf.st_size, 1, fileA);
```

Of course you should check the return values of these functions and take appropriate action.

Comment: I wish I could give this answer my approval, but for the following reasons I can't: 1. The question doesn't mention POSIX, and fstat doesn't exist in standard C. 2. Even when this is compiled in a POSIX C environment, off_t (the type of buf.st_size) might represent higher values than size_t (the type of fread's second argument). If that happens, this code might not read the entire file. 3. Even when compiled in a POSIX C environment, and size_t can represent all of the positive values of off_t, potentially reading 2GB into an array seems absurd!

Comment: I was making a few assumptions. As to the potential file size as the OP is reading it into memory one can assume that the file being read is not going to be that large. The `fstat` could be overcome using `fseek` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why question such a small part of your algorithm? It might be a better idea to take a more wholistic look at your entire algorithm. Your current algorithm depends upon this rather intensive and unnecessary code. If you can remove this dependancy of reading entire files into memory, then your solution will be far more scalable. Perhaps by "a way to do this better", you mean "faster" or "so I can process files that are 100GB in size without crawling to a halt".

Consider a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) that can read, process and extract the required information from your file one byte at a time. You probably wouldn't need malloc so much. Without a specific description of your problem, we can't help you derive a finite state machine to solve your problem. However, one example that stands out might be finding a maximum integer in a 100GB file:

```
while (fscanf(file, "%d", &current_num) == 1) {
    if (current_num > max_num) {
        max_num = current_num;
    }
}
```

This code clearly doesn't need malloc, let alone to read the entire file into memory; It'll only ever use a constant amount of memory, regardless of the size of the file.